# Storage.Builder(com.google.api.client.http....)

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

where can i find the source code for this constructor, we are wondering about the http connection we use in this constructor, will this be open as long as the Storage instance alive? 
or do we reconnect each time we invoke a Storage method?
in the example below do we open a http connection to the cloud and get the bucket and close the connection? or do we keep it open? how does it work?

```
// Set up global Storage instance.
      client = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
          .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

      // Get metadata about the specified bucket.
      Storage.Buckets.Get getBucket = client.buckets().get(BUCKET_NAME);
```

Thanks,
Snabel

Answer (score 0):

HTTP connection is managed by the NetHttpTransport class [1] and will be handled automatically after Storage client is properly constructed. No need to open and close. Storage client should be constructed again on every app run.

[1] - http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.14.1-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/javanet/GoogleNetHttpTransport.html